# OpenGL: Objects rotating strangely

Tags: python, opengl, rotation, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I have a cube object that I am constantly rotating, but I ran into an issue. If I move the object away from (0,0,0), the object begins to rotate in a strange way. I have no idea why and how to fix this.

This is what my object looks like:

[image]

and this is how I rotate the cube:

```py
    def draw_edges(self, color):
        """Draws the cube's edges"""
        glPushMatrix()
        glRotate(self.rotation[3],self.rotation[0],self.rotation[1],self.rotation[2])
        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        for edge in self.edges:
            for vertex in edge:
                glColor3fv(color)
                glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertex])
        glEnd()
        glPopMatrix()
```

and I call a rotate method on the cube that adds the passed in values to the position:

```py
    def rotate(self, rotval, mult):
        self.rotation[0] = rotval[0]
        self.rotation[1] = rotval[1]
        self.rotation[2] = rotval[2]
        self.rotation[3] += mult
        if self.rotation[3] >= 360:
            self.rotation[3] = self.rotation[3] - 360
```

Can anyone help with this.

Comment: How do you "move the object away"? You have to translate the object by `glTranslate` and to rotate by `glRotate`.

Comment: In addition, the matrix operations performed by `glTranslate` and `glRotate` are not commutative, which means the order in which they are applied is critical. As the previous comment suggests, the most helpful thing you can do is show us the code that's responsible for moving the cube.

Comment: @PaulM. I don't think that the contributor "moves" the object by `glTranslate`. Probably the mesh is "moved" by a manipulation of the vertex coordinates, which corresponds to `rotate * translate` rather than `translate * rotate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) matrix operations like [`glTranslate`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glTranslate.html) and [`glRotate`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glRotate.html) specify a new matrix an multiply the current matrix by the new matrix.
Matrix multiplication is not [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). Hence there is a difference, whether you call `glTranslate` and then `glRotate` or `glRotate` followed by `glTranslate`.

When `glRotate` is followed by `glTranslate`, the translated object rotates around the origin:

[image]

When `glTranslate` is followed by `glRotate`, then the object rotates and the rotated object is translated:

[image]

If you translate the mesh, by adding an offset to the vertices, this corresponds to the later. But if you want to rotate the mesh around the origin of the mesh, then you have to translate the rotated model (`translate * rotate`).

Use `glTranslate` to "move" the mesh:

```py
def draw_edges(self, color):
        
    """Draws the cube's edges"""
    glPushMatrix()

    glTranslate(self.x, self.y, self.z)
    glRotate(self.rotation[3],self.rotation[0],self.rotation[1],self.rotation[2])    

    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in self.edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glColor3fv(color)
            glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertex])
    glEnd()
    glPopMatrix()
```